# Check if string (or split string) contains any words from list

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

I have a Twitter bot that needs to ignore tweets that contain certain blacklisted words.

This works, but only if the words in the tweet are exactly as they're seen in the list of blacklisted words.

```
timeline = filter(lambda status: not any(word in status.text.split() for word in wordBlacklist), timeline)
```

I want to make sure that tweets can't bypass this by putting symbols or adding additional characters around a word, such as bypassing blacklisted word "face" by appending "book" to the end of it, like so "facebook".

How do I do this in a way that fits within my filter's lambda?

Comment: Sounds like a job for regular expressions.

Comment: What does "putting symbols" mean?

Comment: An example along with expected output would be more appropriate.

Comment: @J0HN Sorry, I didn't mean replacing characters with symbols, just appending them.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about - I asked for clarification, you responded when you have time. Everyone is happy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `re` here.

```
import re
timeline = filter(lambda status: not any(re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]*"+word+r"[a-zA-Z0-9]*",status.text) for word in wordBlacklist), timeline)
```

You can also use `re.escape()` over `word` if `word` can contain some escape characters

If you expect `symbols` as well ,try

```
timeline = filter(lambda status: not any(re.findall(r"\S*"+word+r"\S*",status.text) for word in wordBlacklist), timeline)
```

Comment: How does it help against "putting symbols"? If I do understand OPs the intention right, `b0t` and `bot` should be treated as the same word. But I might be msitaking.

Comment: I would love to see a small regex-based fix for that, even if OP didn't mention that. By that, I mean using numbers, punctuation and other stuff instead of letters, aka l33t sp3/\k.

Comment: @J0HN if word is `bot` and text has `sdfdbot213123` this can be detected...i have edited for it..... but `bot` changed to `b0t` is tough considering there would be many scenarios

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. :) OP haven't yet answered my question about what he exactly meant, so it might make sense to wait for the nswer.

Comment: @J0HN as of now this answer stands valid as per the trivial example shown by OP :)

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a regular expression based on the blacklist:

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse
import re

wordBlacklist = ['face', 'hello']

r = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, wordBlacklist)))

...
timeline = list(ifilterfalse(lambda status: r.search(status.text), timeline))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of filter, you can use a list comprehension, which is the same idea with a slightly different syntax, and then use regular expressions for the filtering, as your example is beyond the capabilities of string operations:

```
import re
blacklist = re.compile('face|friend|advertisement')
timeline = [word for word in status.split() if not blacklist.search(word)]
# filter version of this command:
timeline = filter(lambda word: not blacklist.search(word), status.split())
```

Now timeline will return a list of words that don't have any match to your blacklist within them, so "facebook" would be blocked because it matches "face", "friendly" would be blocked because it contains "friend", etc. However, you are going to need to get fancier for things like "f*acebook" or other tricks-- these would bypass the filter currently. Try out regex and get comfortable with them, and you can really make pretty fancy filters. [Here is a good practice site for regex.](https://regex101.com/)